# Inserting New Rows Using a ResultSet by JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

I have several questions on Inserting New Rows Using a ResultSet by JDBC. Can you please take a look? Thanks.

In K&B7 Page 895, there is a sample code as follows:

```
1 String query = "SELECT AuthorID, FirstName, LastName FROM Author";
2 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
3 rs.next();
4 rs.moveToInsertRow();
5 rs.updateInt("AuthorID", 1055);
6 rs.updateString("FirstName", "Tom");
7 rs.updateString("LastName", "McGinn");
8 rs.insertRow();
9 rs.moveToCurrentRow();
```

Question 1: Can I delete line 3, so that the cursor is pointing above the first row before we move the cursor to the insert row? Is this allowed?

Question 2: After executing line 8, where is the new row inserted in the database? Is it always appended in the end of the database as the last row no matter where the cursor was pointing in the result set before it was moved to the insert row?

Question 3: After executing line 8, if I want to insert another new row, do I need to add another line "rs.moveToInsertRow();" in the code?

Question 4: Between the line 7 and line 8, if I add a new line "rs.next();", will this lead to throw SQLException in runtime because next() method is not allowed when the cursor is in the insert row?

Answer (score 2):

> Question 1: Can I delete line 3, so that the cursor is pointing above the first row before we move the cursor to the insert row? Is this allowed?

Yes.  Note also that the query might have returned zero rows, in which case you cannot successfully advance the cursor anyway.

> Question 2: After executing line 8, where is the new row inserted in the database? Is it always appended in the end of the database as the last row no matter where the cursor was pointing in the result set before it was moved to the insert row?

"Where in the database?" is not really a meaningful question.  If you mean "where in the result set", the answer is very likely *nowhere*.  The `ResultSet` gives you a means to insert rows into the database, but any such rows cannot have been among the results when the query was executed.

> Question 3: After executing line 8, if I want to insert another new row, do I need to add another line "rs.moveToInsertRow();" in the code?

No.

> Question 4: Between the line 7 and line 8, if I add a new line "rs.next();", will this lead to throw SQLException in runtime because next() method is not allowed when the cursor is in the insert row?

That's unspecified, which in practice means "not a good idea".  I can see several plausible results:

- An `SQLException` is thrown
- `rs.next()` returns `false` without changing anything
- The behavior is equivalent to invoking `rs.moveToCurrentRow()`, then `rs.next()`
- The behavior is equivalent to invoking `rs.moveToCurrentRow()`, then `rs.next()`, then `rs.moveToInsertRow()`

That's not necessarily an exhaustive list.  Very likely, different JDBC drivers handle the situation differently, which is an excellent reason to avoid allowing the situation to arise.

Comment: Question 2: My question is: where is the new row inserted in the database's table? (Is it true that the new inserted row is always put as the last row in the database's table?)

Question 3: The reason why I ask this question is I have seen a code used by Java doc which calls the moveToInsertRow() method a second time when they insert a second row. Please check the following webpage:
[link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/jdbcrowset.html#inserting-row)
Still you think it is not necessary to call the moveToInsertRow() method a second time when they insert a second row?

Comment: @student: formally, there is no "last" row in a table, because tables are *unordered* sets of tuples.  That's why your question is not meaningful.

Comment: @student, `insertRow()` should not move the `ResultSet` cursor.  It is not harmful to invoke `moveToInsertRow()` when the cursor is already on the insert row, but neither is it necessary.  You could put in the extra invocation if you want, perhaps as a defensive coding measure, but if you ever run into a driver that *does* move the cursor off the insert row when you invoke `insertRow()`, then that will be detected in testing against that driver.

Comment: Dear John, Thank you for your reply. I agree it's always a good habit that we write some small code and run experiments ourselves, and that's my way to prepare for my OCP 804 exam, especially for Chapters 13 and 14 on Threads. But unfortunately, I have no access to a database, and that's why I did not run experiments myself for JDBC. Hence, I decided to post my very first question here and yes, this is my first time. Thank you for your patience and help!